# SimpleModal - scroll floated div

Tags: css, scrollbar, simplemodal

I am using jQuery SimpleModal in order to display product information. For this I have two divs which are to be shown in one modal dialog: The left div holds the product logo and some description right underneath the logo. The right div holds detailled information about the product. The content in the right div can become quite long.

What I need the modal dialog to do is to keep the left div at its position while the right div scrolls if its content is too long. How can this be accomplished?

Here is my HTML structure within the modal dialog:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftColumn">
        <div id="picture">
        </div>

        <div id="information">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightColumn">
        <p>Looooong text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the according CSS:

```
#leftColumn {
    float: left;
}

#rightColumn {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use positioning in these divs it will be greatly helpful
setting up `max-width:as you require;` `max-height:auto;` can help you